# How to retrieve only containers running a specific image in go-dockerclient?

Tags: go, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am using [go-dockerclient](https://github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient) library to retrieve list of containers I got all containers by using the [ListContainers function](https://godoc.org/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient#Client.ListContainers)

```
conts, err := client.ListContainers(docker.ListContainersOptions{All: true})
```

But I want to get only containers that are running a specific image
I tried running

```
conts, err := client.ListContainers(docker.ListContainersOptionsFilters: map[string][]string{"Image": {"<imagename>:<version>"}}})
```

but I got the error Invalid filter:'Image' meaning that there is no filter field called Image

So does anybody have a solution to get only containers that are running a specific image?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of image field you should use ancestor so you can use

```
conts, err :=client.ListContainers(docker.ListContainersOptionsFilters: map[string][]string{"ancestor": {"<imagename>:<version>"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just see the docker ps filter options, the website below lists all filters supported currently.
https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/docs/reference/commandline/ps.md